# Question about beat frequencies of light

Tags: discussion

Someone recently asked a question about whether you could observe beat frequencies of light. I think it was within the last week. Can anyone remember the question? Despite what I think are obvious search terms I'm unable to find the question.

I ask because a [paper has just appeared on the Arxiv demonstrating exactly this effect](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2384) and I think this would make a nice answer to the question if only I could find it.

Comment: Well, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56144/ is more than a year old. Nice preprint, too.

Comment: This one? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/118897/

Comment: Thanks both, but I was sure there was a question within the last week or so. Maybe the OP decided to delete it.

Comment: Are you sure it was a new question, or was it just active recently?

Comment: I think it must have been [the question dmckee linked](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56144/can-light-waves-cause-beats), though that's from 2013. How I saw it I don't know. Maybe it appeared in a review queue.

Comment: Potentially [this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134499/how-to-shift-a-laser-wavelength), maybe?